# Getting error while trying to use .mdf file in Windows Forms

Tags: sql-server, windows, forms, mdf

I am trying to use a `.mdf` file with Windows Forms but I'm getting an Error.

This is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=HospitalManagmentSystem;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\HospitalManagmentSystem.mdf";
```

For error please check screenshot:

[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: Does that file mentioned in your error message exist??

Comment: Yes, it does exists, but still getting this issue, don't know why

Comment: Can you show us the **complete** error messages? Try clicking on "Copy exception details to clipboard" in this dialog, and then post whatever you get from the clipboard here (by editing your question and adding this information)